# bootstrap scrollspy not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

Here is what the problem i am facing.

http://bittu.github.com/folderGrid/

It is highlighting last tab at first and when scrolling it switches between only two tags on each step of scroll.

Here is small snippet of code i used.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subnav" data-offset="50">

<div class="subnav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#contents">Contents</a></li>
        <li><a href="#config">Config Options</a></li>
        <li><a href="#usage">Usage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#examples">Examples</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <section id="contents">
            ....
        </section>
        <section id="config">
            ....
        </section>
        <section id="usage">
            ....
        </section>
        <section id="examples">
            ....
       </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Included all necessary files. and tried all numbers for `data-offset`

Comment: Is this resolved? The snippet seems to be working. Which answer fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's bootstrap does not define `subnav` class. It is provided in Twitter's page for Bootstrap, but to reuse it you have to include some code from their [CSS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/docs.css). It is designed exclusively for this particular page. Subnav is fixing position when scrolling, to see how it works take a look into the CSS and [JS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/application.js).

Comment: i have included their CSS as well as JS for positioning the navbar to TOP...
Well please check my link in the question... It is a live working example of my problem...

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem few hours ago. I use it in the same way you did (spy at `body` and use `section` as target). 
In the end, I found that I simply missed the `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of the file, though I checked your demo site and there is a html5 declaration already.

By the way I switched to the bootstrap v2.1